# How to use the concept behind listview in php?

Tags: php, listview

I was asked by a friend to add something to her website. She wants her user to create a customized packages for themselves. And I was told by someone I can use the concept of LIST VIEW wherein there are add, delete, move all, remove all, reset buttons.

There would be the DEFAULT PACKAGE and the CUSTOMIZED PACKAGE.

I searched the net, but all i can find the listview connected to a datagrid. I don't need that actually, as far as i can understand this, all i need is to use the concept behind the list view. Because after all the selection, the user will submit the customized package and the ADMIN and the USER itself will receive an email containing the details.

I am a really a newbie in php. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at shopping cart code to learn how to add and remove things to the customised packages. There are many shopping cart tutorials. A particularly simple one is here http://www.phpwebcommerce.com/.

As for writing the email use this code [1]

```
$to = "recipient@example.com";
$subject = "Hi!";
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
    echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
} 
else {
    echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
}
```

[1} From  http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/How_to_Send_Email_from_a_PHP_Script.htm. I normally don't use about.com but this is really simple code.

Good luck!

Comment: By the way, it is great to have a complete newbie asking questions. Please feel free to ask me if you have any further questions.

Comment: hi @brett, thank you! but actually there is a mistake with my question. i was really referring to a listbox, not a list view.

Comment: anyway i am already studying the link you gave me which i saw earlier too but too scared to read what it contains. I'm not really a programmer.
i'm confused, can i use the inventory system tutorials instead? the shopping cart and the inventory system are just the same, right?

Comment: Hi @Akosirenee you can use either. What ever makes sense to you.